# Open only one dropdown in within an array of cards

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array of news that I'm displaying through Material-ui components, while mapping over it when I click on one dropdown to show more from the description, all the cards opens up instead of only the one I clicked on. I would like to avoid this behaviour. If you can answer my question it will be appreciated. The code is this

```
{Articles.map((article, index) => {
    return (
    <>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Card key={index} className={classes.root}>
            <CardHeader
            action={
                <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
            }
            title={article.title}
            subheader={new Date(article.publishedAt).toLocaleString(
                "it-IT",
                options
            )}
            />
            <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image={article.urlToImage}
            title={article.title}
            />
            <CardContent>
            <Typography
                variant="body2"
                color="textSecondary"
                component="p"
            >
                {article.description}
            </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
                <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton
                className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                })}
                onClick={handleExpandClick}
                aria-expanded={expanded}
                aria-label="scopri di piu"
            >
                <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
            <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography paragraph>{article.content}</Typography>

                <Typography>
                Per leggere l'intero articolo clicca{" "}
                <a
                    href=""
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer noopener canonical"
                >
                    qui
                </a>
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
        </Card>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        </Grid>
    </>
    )
})}
</Grid>
```

The `handleExpandClick` function

```
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)
  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded)
  }
```

Comment: You're passing a single `expanded` state to all child components, so setting it true, sets them all true. You need to move the expanded state to the child component, so that each individual card knows if it is expanded or not. Also using index as key (`key={index}`) is [not recommended](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: I should use the index as a parameter in the function, I could filter an array duplicate, I just don't know the smartest way to go